# Let 3rd party work on Symfony design without access to complete project/source

Tags: symfony

I am working on a Symfony 2 WebApp. The WebApp has been online for about two years, now I would like to update the design. This work should be outsourced to a 3rd party.

Of course the designer needs access to all styles (sass files) and templates (twig files) to work on the design. How can I do this, without giving him access to the complete rest of the project as well?

At first the questions seems obvious: Create an user account (e.g. FTP) that allows access only for the style/image/template folders.

Problem is, that I do not have a root server on which I could specify user access for individual folders. The access control I can us is quite limited: A FTP user can only be limited to a root folder but than has access to **all** child folders. SSH users cannot be limited to any folder at all.

Setting up a root server with full access control to let the designer do his job would be possible of course. However I consider this solution to be an overkill.

Another solution would be to create a special branch of the project which all important/confidential source code remove. Of course the branch would still have to be usable but with a limited feature set. This would be possible but more work than doing the design on my own.

**Long story short:** Is there any standard way of letting 3rd parties work dedicated parts of a Symfony project without giving them access to the whole project?

**EDIT:**

Of course the designer needs some kind of access to a ***running* instance/copy** of the web app. Giving him a standalone copy of the templates/styles folder would be possible and secure (no other code is made public), but in this case it would be impossible to view the result of changes.

Comment: That's an interesting topic. Anyway, restricting access to particular directories (web, views, etc. ), may not work. How could the 3rd party work on twig templates without the rest of the project? They won't be able to open anything in browser. I'm curious how you see that working assuming you'll succeed with your issue.

Comment: I don't see the problem: If the app is hosted on my server/webspace and the designer has only access to the twig templates (within the web app, not as standalone folder), changes in a template file will become visible when the page is refreshed. However the designer does not only need access to one folder but to quite a lot. Solving this with a lot of different FTP accounts would possible but impractical. Additionally when using Compass or other tools that need to 'compile' the code, simple FTP access is not enough of course.

Comment: Well then it's important information for you issue. You want them to work on your server and modify it in **real-time**. Therefore git branch probably won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account comments under the question, I would suggest to create FTP user with restricted access to only his *home* directory.

Then put there all directories that he needs. Something like this:

```
/ftpuser_home
    /views
    /web
    /sass
    /anything-other
```

Last step is to symlink each of these directories to the running project instance directory under appropriate paths like

```
/ftpuser_home/views => /var/www/symfony/app/Resources/views
```

And so on.

This way they can work with your project. Once they're finished, you simply remove symlinks, physically move directories back to the project directory and commit changes to git.

**Note:** It could look like it would be easier to do it *vice versa*, which is to create symlinks in `/ftpuser_home` not in project directory, but you probably would come across permissions issues.

You you're not afraid of them and know how to solve them, then it may work even better.

Comment: This approach sound promissing. However there is one problem: Hardlinks are not possible for directories, and Symlinks cannot be used access directories outside the folder tree that can be accessed with FTP itself. Thus I could only symlink directories within `ftpuser_home` which does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: That's why I suggested to move these directories to `ftpuser_home` and make symlinks in webserver project directory. That may require some additional Apache configuration if `ftpuser_home` is out of Apache's Document root where it doesn't have access, but I'm not sure about that.